# Passing the input value form an input box to another private sub code?

Tags: vba, inputbox

So basically i am trying to do the following:

1. When a specific sheet is activated/selected, i want an input box to
   be displayed.
2. From that input box i want to get a specific range that can be found
   in that specific sheet.

Now, once that custom range is defined, i will use another private sub to analyze if the required conditions are met in that specific range (which was defined by the input box).

Below are the codes that i am currently using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim x As Range
Set x = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the range you want to be verified for results", Title:="Notifier", Default:="Ex: $A$5:$B$30", Type:=8)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim A As Range
   Dim r As Range
   Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   Set A = x.Range
   If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   For Each r In Target
       If r.Value = "FAIL" Then
          intMessage = MsgBox("Please be aware that you have marked one of the required verification points as [Fail]" & vbCr _
          & vbCr _
          & "To improve the visibility over this issue please submit a new Jira ticket for it." & vbCr _
          & vbCr _
          & "Would you like to create the ticket now?", _
          vbYesNo, "Notifier")
          If intMessage = vbYes Then
          objShell.Run ("https://custom_link")
          Else
          End If
       End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the thing, i am trying to figure out how to trigger that input box on sheet selection and then use that input value to analyze if there are any cell changes that match my criteria. If there are then the second code will prompt a message box which redirects me to that custom link. That's the plan

Comment: Solved it, i had to declare x at the very top of my code. Before starting the subs. Thanks for the help.